# Resolving implicit parameter at runtime

Tags: scala, apache-spark, implicit

I know implicits are resolved during compilation time, so I guess I'm looking for a workaround for the following. Let's say I have a method with this signature:

```
class MyClass {
  def run[X](x: X)(implicit runnable: Runnable[X]) = runnable(x)
}
```

I want to wrap it:

```
class MyClassWrapper[Z: ClassTag] {
  val rdd: RDD[Z] = //Spark RDD
  def runWrapper[X](fun: Z => X) = rdd.foreach( (el:Z) => new MyClass.run(fun(el)))
}
```

This will not compile complaining about not being able to find an implicit. I could change the signature to:

```
def runWrapper[X](fun: Z => X)(implicit runnable: Runnable[X])
```

And all would compile but I'm using Spark which does not allow not Serializable objects to be captured inside operations from the outside (in my case the `run` would capture the implicit parameter from `runWrapper`) so I do need to get/create that implicit **inside** the `run` instead of closing it in from outside. Is that possible?

Comment: Could you not get the parameter upon creation of the class? i.e. `MyClassWrapper[Z](implicit runnable: Runnable[Z])`? The `implicit` needs to be resolved when the type of `Z` is known.

Comment: @yw3410 It needs the runnable of `X` (the result of the `fun` function), not `Z`, and thus it's not available at `MyClassWrapper` creation.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible then as the `implicit` needs to be of a known type before it's resolved. However, I think that you'll be able to get the behavior you want if you know all the values of possible `X` if a little messy. Do you know all the possible types that `X` can be?

Comment: I could go through the library's source code and get them but that's not really a solution I'd want to go with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't come up with anything in runtime (didn't want to try reflection) so I ended up writing a few versions of the method, one per each type (since they don't share any common parent)

```
class MyClassWrapper[Z: ClassTag] {
  val rdd: RDD[Z] = //Spark RDD
  def runWrapper(fun: Z => Implementation1) = rdd.foreach( (el:Z) => new MyClass.run(fun(el)))

  def runWrapper(fun: Z => Implementation2) = rdd.foreach( (el:Z) => new MyClass.run(fun(el)))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to instanciate the implicit inside the foreach:

```
def runWrapper[X](fun: Z => X) = rdd.foreach{ (el:Z) => 
   val runnable = implicitly[Runnable[X]]
   new MyClass.run(fun(el))(runnable)
}
```

Comment: This generates the same code as explicitly adding the argument as an implicit parameter, thus is not what Mateusz is looking for. (implicitly is simply a different way to de-facto have an implicit parameter list without writing it directly)